# How to improve this JS code to look more elegant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my React app using Material UI, I wrote a code to manage the size of the fields of a contact form. Those fields are elements that can be added or removed depending on a configuration.

The code I wrote works as expected but looks ugly and I need help to make it better.

```
let size = 12;
    if (useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('sm'))) {
      const hasTime = fieldsConfig.some(
        f => f.name === 'preferredContactHours',
      );
      const hasContactType = fieldsConfig.some(
        f => f.name === 'preferredContactWay',
      );
      if (name === 'phone' && (!hasTime || !hasContactType)) size = 7;
      else if (name === 'preferredContactWay' && hasTime) size = 6;
      else if (name === 'preferredContactWay' && !hasTime) size = 5;
      else if (name === 'preferredContactHours' && hasContactType) size = 6;
      else if (name === 'preferredContactHours' && !hasContactType) size = 5;
    }
```

The size is 12 by default, so if any of the conditions are not applicable, the field will still be full size in the grid.

The fields `hasTime` and `hasContactType` are optional so I need to check if they are present or not.

The rest is checking if the fields are or aren't there and setting sizes accordingly.

What I'd need is to have it better and more efficient than all this verbose code, if that's possible.

Comment: consider using [CodeReview Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for code improvement/review

Comment: Starting with `if (name === 'phone')`, is `name` in scope?

Comment: name is the name of the field we have the phone and else in that

Comment: `else if (name === 'preferredContactWay') size = hasTime ? 6 : 5;` or maybe just `else `size = (hasTime || hasContactType) ? 6 : 5`

Comment: @epascarello just to understand `if (name === 'phone' && (!hasTime || !hasContactType)) size = 7; 
if size = (hasTime || hasContactType) ? 6 : 5`  or the other way you suggested

Comment: @epascarello with your solution the else size = ... when I deactivate both fields the phone field is not going to b2 12 but remain 7 actually can you help m to optimize it better

Comment: I'm voting to close this as **needs more focus** since the scope is beyond that of SO. It has [been posted on Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/249363/120114)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve the quality of the code. This is not the only way. I think this can turn your code in a more high cohesion e less coupled style. Hope this helps you.

p.s. I not tested the code.

```js
const sizeResult = document.querySelector('#size')

let size = 12
    
const name = 'preferredContactWay'

const fieldsConfig = [{ name: 'preferredContactHoursss' }]

const useMediaQuery = () => true

// Object size configuration. This helps to avoid `if`s.
const sizeConfiguration = {
  preferredContactWay_true: 6,
  preferredContactWay_false: 6,
  preferredContactHours_true: 6,
  preferredContactHours_false: 6,
  phone: 7, 
}

/* SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). One of the SOLID principles and a good practice of  the Clean Architecture 
Each function must have only one reason to change (single responsibility)
*/
function getHasTimeValue() {
  return fieldsConfig.some(
    f => f.name === 'preferredContactHours',
  )
}

function getHasContactTypeValue() {
  return fieldsConfig.some(
    f => f.name === 'preferredContactWay',
  )
}

function getSize(_name) {
  const param = getHasTimeValue() ? getHasTimeValue() : getHasContactTypeValue()

  return param ? sizeConfiguration[`${_name}_${param}`] : sizeConfiguration['phone']
}

function Main() {
  if (useMediaQuery()) {
    size = getSize(name)
    sizeResult.innerHTML = size
  } 
}

Main()


sizeResult.innerHTML = size
```

```html
<div id="size"></div>
```

Comment: The issue is that like this breaks the code I have https://pastebin.com/DCkPsK3W
maybe looking on my Pastebin can make your help batter if you can please check and tell me a different solution

Comment: I've noted that this snippet brakes in the stackoverflow engine. But runs well on the codepen.

Comment: I see but using the Pastebin part? can you paste me here a version more react friendly please

Comment: also as the thing, you are not considering that both fields can be false so the phone should be 12 then

Comment: You're right. I forgot the `phone` . Updated the answer.